# How do I flip .html pages with pure CSS3?

Tags: iphone, animation, webkit, css, flip

I'm looking for a tutorial without any javascript - pure CSS3.
I've created two pages (page1.html, page2.html) for the iPhone and I'm using CSS3 and the -webkit-properties.

To connect those sites I created a next- and a backbutton. 
When tapping on the nextbutton page2.html is loaded, when tapping on the backbutton page1.html is loaded.

This is working so far.

I'd like to try using some more -webkit-properties to get the flip-effect like in [this demo](http://www.qmobile.com.au/examples/css3flip/).

So, when clicking on my next-button page2.html should be flipped in. When clicking/tapping on the backbutton page1.html should be flipped in.

I'm new to this and hope to get some help here. Do you know a tutorial dealing with my problem?

Another question coming up to my mind was whether it is possible to load page2.html seperatly or whether I have to build only one page with the content of page1.html and page2.html?

Comment: **Note**: `-webkit` properties are not part of the CSS3 standard, they are private Safari extensions to CSS. You should use `transform` and use `-webkit-transform` only as a fallback.

Comment: How are you going to handle a click or tap using CSS?

Comment: @Franci Penov - Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

You have to build only one page with two sections/divs with the flip-contents in it. Then you can use the `transform: rotateY` … or, maybe load the second page in with AXAJ or something else, but because it's CSS on my understanding you have to put everything in one page with two sections/divs

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of pageflip demos on the interwebs. [This is one we did](http://dev.sencha.com/animator/demos/pageflip/) It was inspired by [Roman Cortes](http://www.romancortes.com/blog/pure-css3-page-flip-effect/) one - there are others that use more of a squeeze than a flip.